# Using protocol Modbus in Java (Jamod library), "master" don`t see the "slave"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, modbus

Using protocol Modbus, I need to emulate simple "slave" and "master" and exchange the data between them. I use java and I choosed a `Jamod` library. I found simple example of "slave" [here](http://jamod.sourceforge.net/development/udp_slave_howto.html) and "master" [here](http://jamod.sourceforge.net/development/udp_master_howto.html), but I can`t run it correctly.

This is my code of the "slave":

```
import net.wimpi.modbus.Modbus;
import net.wimpi.modbus.net.*;
import net.wimpi.modbus.procimg.*;
import net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusCoupler;

public class UDPSlaveTest { // UDP Slave
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* The important instances and variables */
    ModbusUDPListener listener = null;
    SimpleProcessImage spi = null;
    int port = Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT;

    //1. Set port number from commandline parameter
    if(args != null && args.length ==1) {
        port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }

    //2. Prepare a process image
    spi = new SimpleProcessImage();
    spi.addDigitalOut(new SimpleDigitalOut(true));
    spi.addDigitalOut(new SimpleDigitalOut(false));
    spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(false));
    spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(true));
    spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(false));
    spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(true));
    spi.addRegister(new SimpleRegister(251));
    spi.addInputRegister(new SimpleInputRegister(45));

    //3. Prepare coupler holding image reference
    ModbusCoupler.getReference().setProcessImage(spi);
    ModbusCoupler.getReference().setMaster(false);
    ModbusCoupler.getReference().setUnitID(15);

    //4. Create a listener with 3 threads in pool
    listener = new ModbusUDPListener();
    listener.setPort(port);
    listener.start();
}
}
```

And this is my code of the "master":

```
import java.net.*;
import net.wimpi.modbus.*;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.*;
import net.wimpi.modbus.io.*;
import net.wimpi.modbus.net.*;

public class UDPDITest { // UDP Master
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   /* The important instances of the classes mentioned before */
    UDPMasterConnection con = null; //the connection
    ModbusUDPTransaction trans = null; //the transaction
    ReadInputDiscretesRequest req = null; //the request
    ReadInputDiscretesResponse res = null; //the response

    /* Variables for storing the parameters */
    InetAddress addr = null; //the slave's address
    int port = Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT;
    int ref = 0; //the reference; offset where to start reading from
    int count = 0; //the number of DI's to read
    int repeat = 1; //a loop for repeating the transaction

    //1. Setup the parameters
    if (args.length < 3) {
        System.exit(1);
    } else {
        try {
            String astr = args[0];
            int idx = astr.indexOf(':');
            if(idx > 0) {
                port = Integer.parseInt(astr.substring(idx+1));
                astr = astr.substring(0,idx);
            }
            addr = InetAddress.getByName(astr);
            ref = Integer.decode(args[1]).intValue();
            count = Integer.decode(args[2]).intValue();
            if (args.length == 4) {
                repeat = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    //2. Open the connection
    con = new UDPMasterConnection(addr);
    con.setPort(port);
    con.connect();

    //3. Prepare the request
    req = new ReadInputDiscretesRequest(ref, count);

    //4. Prepare the transaction
    trans = new ModbusUDPTransaction(con);
    trans.setRequest(req);

    //5. Execute the transaction repeat times
    int k = 0;
    do {
        trans.execute();
        res = (ReadInputDiscretesResponse) trans.getResponse();
        System.out.println("Digital Inputs Status=" + res.getDiscretes().toString());
        k++;
    } while (k < repeat);

    //6. Close the connection
    con.close();
}//main
}//class UDPDITest
```

I run UDPSlaveTest from IntelliJ IDEA using parameter `"5555"`. When it is running, I run ModbusTCPMaster from IntelliJ IDEA using parameters `"localhost:5555 0 4 3"`, but I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at jamod_official.UDPDITest.main(UDPDITest.java:65)
```

so there is no any response from the "slave".

Help me, please, how to connect to it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In my view, a developer should not write too many lines of code to connect to a device when he uses some protocol library.

Try the Modbus Modern API - Java from www.daacoworks.com.

Comment: As I see, this solution costs 400$, if it isn`t trial version. But I am working now with free library for educational purposes.

Comment: Ok fine. if it is educational purposes, why don't you try the trial version? The trial version has full feature set but runs for only four hours continuously. you have to restart your application after four hours of run. I believe that should be ok to you.